# error : Can't read "n" : no such variable in tcl

Tags: variables, tcl, upvar

```
proc rep {name} {
    upvar $name n 
    puts "nm is $n"
}
```

In the above procedure, '`name`' is a parameter which is passed to a procedure named '`rep`'.  When I run this program I got  "`error : Can't read "n"  : no such variable`". Could any one tell me what could be the possible cause for this error.

Comment: Probably that the variable which name is in $name doesn't exist. `upvar` doesn't check that.

Answer (score 5):

That error message would be produced if the variable whose name you passed to `rep` did not exist in the calling scope. For example, check this interactive session with tclsh…

```
% proc rep {name} {
    upvar $name n 
    puts "nm is $n"
}
% rep foo
can't read "n": no such variable
% set foo x
x
% rep foo
nm is x
```

### Going deeper…

The variable `foo` is in a funny state after the `upvar` if it is unset; it's actually existing (it's referenced in the global namespace's hash table of variables) but has no contents, so tests of whether it exists fail. (A variable is said to exist when it has an entry somewhere — that is, some storage to put its contents in — and it has a value set in that storage; an unset variable can be one that has a `NULL` at the C level in that storage. The Tcl language itself does not support `NULL` values at all for this reason; they correspond to non-existence.)

Comment: As for why your code is failing, I'm guessing you passed the wrong variable name in or called it from the wrong scope. Easily done.

Comment: This is so helpful. I was having similar issues but never thought of scope.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this too. I realized I was sending $foo instead of foo (note, no dollar sign).

```
% set foo 1
%
% rep $foo
can't read "foo": no such variable
%
% rep foo
nm is 1
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This answer does not explain the difference between evaluating a variable with the $ or just using the variable...but I can saw that from reading this it made me realize I too was trying to evaluate when I don't need to for an application.